# FOS Elastica how to apply indexable_callback for level 2 entities?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

Let's say, I have a "book" and an "author" entity;

Then entity `book` has a `getPublic()` method that that returns "true" if the book is public. 
In the mapping config I use

```
 book:
            types:
                book:
                    indexable_callback: 'getPublic'
```

And indeed, it only indexes books that have their `getPublic() == true` :+1: 
Lets say I have a book with `"title":"toto"` and `"public":false`, it is not indexed.

Now, I also have an class "author" with an n-to-n relationship with books. 
The mapping are made so that when I index author, I get this

```
"author":{
    "name":"titi",
    "books":[{
        "title": "toto",
        "public": false
    }]
}
```

The problem is: the callback "getPublic" is well triggered for 1st level indexation, and was not called with this "second level". 
Is it normal? And if yes, what would be a workaround? 
Thanks!!